Whats the best way to test OpenAPI generated code with WireMock that runs on dynamic port?
I have Spring Boot 3 application. I use openapi.json to define rest client and openapi-generator-maven-plugin to generate java code for the client. This results in ApiClient class being generated which has field private String basePath whose value is taken from openapi.json
For example:
openapi.json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "Postman Echo API Client",
    "x-revision": "2024-08-20"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://postman-echo.com",
      "description": "Postman Echo Service"
    }
  ],
  // ... more fields
}

Causes
public class ApiClient extends JavaTimeFormatter {
    // ... more fields

    private String basePath = "https://postman-echo.com";
    
    // ... more fields/methods
}

Now to make it configurable I use the following config:
@Configuration
public class EchoApiConfig {

  @Value("${rest.clients.echo.base-path:https://postman-echo.com}")
  private String basePath;

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate (RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public ApiClient apiClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    ApiClient apiclient = new ApiClient(restTemplate);
    apiclient.setBasePath(basePath);
    return apiclient;
  }

  @Bean
  public EchoServiceApi echoServiceApi(ApiClient apiClient) {
    return new EchoServiceApi(apiClient);
  }

}

Now I can configure the path value for WireMock test using propertiesattribute of @SpringBootTest like this:
@EnableWireMock
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
  properties = {"rest.clients.echo.base-path=http://localhost"}
)
class EchoServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private EchoService echoService;

  @Value("${wiremock.server.baseUrl}")
  private String wiremockUrl;

  @Test
  void testWiremock() throws IOException {
    WireMock.stubFor(get(anyUrl()).willReturn(okJson("{\"key\": \"value\"}")));

    echoService.performRequest();

    List<ServeEvent> allServeEvents = WireMock.getAllServeEvents();
    System.out.println(allServeEvents.get(0).getRequest().getUrl());
  }

}

Now the problem is that wiremockUrl is different every time (for example http://localhost:1234 one time and http://localhost:2345 next time and so on) because the free port is different. And I can't just take any port and hardcode assumption that it is free because if I hardcode port 8080 like that properties = {"rest.clients.echo.base-path=http://localhost:8080"} then it could happen that 8080 is already taken and test fails.
Question: What is the best way in test to tell that rest.clients.echo.base-path must be same as wiremock.server.baseUrl?

It turns out that Spring Boot has property placeholder resolution which allows you to write tests like that:
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
  properties = {"rest.clients.echo.base-path=${wiremock.server.baseUrl}"}
)
class EchoServiceTest {
...

And you can even concatenate there other strings like this:
properties = {"rest.clients.echo.base-path=${wiremock.server.baseUrl}/something/else"}

